# Find all x ∈ $(Z/17Z)^×$ such that $⟨x⟩ = (Z/17Z)^×$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find all $x ∈ (Z/17Z)^×$ such that $⟨x⟩ = (Z/17Z)^×$

So I know I'm trying to find all the generators for $(Z/17Z)^×$ and I know that since 17 is prime that the order of $(Z/17Z)^×$ is 16, is there a faster way to find all the generators or do I need to check 1 to 16?

Also since 17 is prime would the generators for $(Z/17Z)^×$ be the same as the generators for $(Z/17Z)$?

Comment: $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic and of the form $\Bbb Z/(p-1)\Bbb Z$ for prime $p$, as you pointed out. Is there something you could use about the gcd of an element and the order of the group that might help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $17$ is a prime of the form $2^k+1$, all the quadratic non-residues $\!\!\pmod{17}$ are generators of the multiplicative group and vice-versa. The least quadratic non-residue $\!\!\pmod{17}$ can be found by brutal inspection:
$$\left(\frac{2}{17}\right)=1,\quad \left(\frac{3}{17}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=-1$$

(we only need to check primes since the least non-quadratic residue is always a prime) Once we have that $3$ is a generator of the multiplicative group, all the other generators are given by the odd powers of 3, or, equivalently, by the set of quadratic residues multiplied by $3$. The quadratic residues are $1^2,2^2,\ldots,8^2$, so the generators are
$$ \{3\cdot 1^2, 3\cdot 2^2,\ldots,3\cdot 8^2\} = \{3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 14\}.$$

Comment: this is super helpful! I'm just confused on how you found it was generated by 3?

Comment: @user520403 If you are confused I wouldn't call it "super helpful". Of course the answer is very helpful.

Comment: @user520403: since the generators *are* the quadratic non-residues, it is enough to check which (small) primes are non-quadratic residues. This scan is very brief: $2$ is a quadratic residue since $17\equiv 1\pmod{8}$, but the prime $3$ is already a non-quadratic residue.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check that $(\mathbb Z/17\mathbb Z)^\times$ is generated by $3$. In other words$$\begin{array}{ccc}(\mathbb Z/16\mathbb Z,+)&\longrightarrow&(\mathbb Z/17\mathbb Z)^\times\\n&\mapsto&3^n\end{array}$$is a group homomorphism. So, which elements of $(\mathbb Z/16\mathbb Z,+)$ generate that group?

Comment: I'm slightly confused on how you found its generated by 3?

Comment: I simply did these computations: $3^2\equiv9\pmod{17}$, $3^4\equiv9^2\equiv13\pmod{17}$, and $3^8\equiv13^2\equiv16\pmod{17}$. So, since the order of $3$ must divide $16$ (by Lagrange's theorem), it must be $16$. In other words, $(\mathbb Z/17\mathbb Z)^\times=\langle 3\rangle$.